# Refetch queries after Mutation doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have mutation as follows:

```
<Mutation
    mutation={ADD_NEW_SLOT}
    refetchQueries={() => [{ query: GET_COMPANY_ADDRESSES, variables: { companyId: this.props.session.company.id } }]}
    awaitRefetchQueries={true}
>
     .......
</Mutation>
```

Where **GET_COMPANY_ADDRESSES** is exported from a parent component.

But it doesn't refresh after the mutation is done.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The return of the render function in the **parent** component is as follows:

```
<Query query={GET_COMPANY_ADDRESSES} variables={{companyId: session.company.id}} notifyOnNetworkStatusChange={true} fetchPolicy={'cache-and-network'}>
    {({loading, error, refetch, data}) => {
        if (loading) return <LoadingIndicator/>;
        if (error) return <ErrorIndicator description={error.message}/>;

        const treeNodes = convertSlotsToTree(data);
        const address = data.companyAddresses[1];

        return (
            <AddSlot address={address}
                     toggleSlotForm={this.props.togglePanel}
                     session={this.props.session}/>
        )
    }}
</Query>
```

The graphql query is in the same file and it is as follows:

```
export const GET_COMPANY_ADDRESSES = gql`
      query CompanyAddresses($companyId: Int!) {
        companyAddresses(companyId: $companyId) {
          id    
          name
          default
          compound
          address {
            id
            addressFull
            countryCode
            city
            postCode
            slotSet{
                id
                area
                zone
                aisle
                side
                level
                position
                disabled
                col
                printEntry
                fullName
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;
```

Comment: That looks right. Do you see the query being fired after your mutation in the network tab? If so, is it the same query and same variables as what's fired by your Query component?

Comment: @DanielRearden Yes. It's the same. Everything looks fine. When I refresh the page I see the new record but the UI doesn't update without manual refresh.

Comment: If the variables are the same for both requests, then it sounds like possibly an issue with your Query component. Can you edit your question to include that code?

Comment: @DanielRearden Updated.

Comment: Apollo recommends to use update prop on Mutation component over refetch.

Comment: @PavanBahuguni And how can I do that?

Comment: @Boky Apollo can handle automatic cache updation as a result of mutation when the type that you are updating is already present in the cache, the problem is when you are creating new things (like adding new type to a list) or deleting something from a list, there is no way for Apollo to figure out what to do, this is where update prop of Mutation comes in handy, which gives you the ability to read data from the cache (i.e exisiting list from the cache) and then append the new value to that list and then write the new list to cache so that it is reflected in your UI.

Comment: @Boky You read about exact implementation here.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#update

Comment: I don't think there's anything particularly wrong with your code. I suspect it's a bug with Apollo; see [this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3633). You could try removing `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange`, changing the `fetchPolicy` and seeing if that helps. I suspect it's one of those two settings not playing well with `refetchQueries`. You could also try passing down the `refetch` function from your query component and using that instead.

Answer (score 4):

It still does not work with react-apollo 3.1.x w/o workaround.

It seems that if you use these two things, updates will be sent to Query:

1. Set option for `Query`: `fetchPolicy="cache-and-network"` (you use this already).
2. Comment `refetchQueries` and use `Query`'s `refetch` instead. Attach function to `Mutation`'s `onCompleted`, and call `refetch` from the `Query` directly. You should see graphql query in HTTP requests, and UI should updates itself as well.

Note. "cache-first" as fetchPolicy did not work, although I guess cache is updated, but UI does not.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular I found this working, as expected (note the "no-cache" flag):

```
this.postsQuery = this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
    query: GET_USER_ON_ROLE,
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    variables: {
      roleId : this.roleId
    }      
  });

this.querySubscription = this.postsQuery
    .valueChanges
    .subscribe(({ data, loading }) => {
      this.loading = loading;
      this.allUsers = data.getAllUsersPerRoleUI;
  });
```

An you need to reload once the mutation is over using `refetch()`:

```
  public reloadFunction()
  {
    this.postsQuery.refetch() 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also stumbled on this error and my solution was to import and use the query in the same component as the mutation. i.e.

```
const {} = useFindAllUsersQuery();
const [createUser] = useCreateUserMutation({
  refetchQueries: ['FindAllUsers']
});
```